# Keyboard layout on Ubuntu won't go away!

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gnome, keyboard-layout

So, I installed Ubuntu (Using Gnome) with keyboard layout US International with Dead Keys enabled. Now I've set this to US International with Alt-Gr Dead Keys enabled. I added the latter and deleted the first. I then clicked "Apply to entire system" and closed the keyboard manager.

Now whenever I reboot, the old keyboard lay-out is re-added to the list and set to the default keyboard layout. The keyboard with US International with Alt-Gr Dead Keys enabled is still in that list so it doesn't completely revert to the installation settings, making me conclude that it must have saved the settings...

How can I make this keyboard ghost go to the eternal `/dev/null/` plane so that it will never rise from the grave again? (How to get rid of the thing...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://askubuntu.com/questions/3355/keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-wont-go-away by Richard Holloway there:

> [Apparently](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1414858) setting the keyboard layout
>   you wish to use when logging in solves
>   this problem.
>
> When logging in, as you are about to
>   enter your password in GDM, there is a
>   discreet menu option on the toolbar at
>   the bottom.
>
> Changing the setting here will cause
>   Ubuntu to use the correct keyboard
>   setting not just for that session but
>   for subsequent log ins.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem with my Ubuntu installation. I installed Ubuntu with a Dvorak keyboard layout and could not switch to a standard layout.

I was able to fix my problem by removing every layout but the layout I wanted to use under keyboard preferences > layout.